# Random variable of supremum of set has distribution F(x)

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

*$F(x)$ is a distribution function. That is, it's nondecreasing, right continuous, $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to \infty} F(x) = 1$, and $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to -\infty} F(x) = 0$.*
*If uniformly distributed random variable $Y$ on $[0,1]$ and
$X=\sup\{x: F(x) < y\}$
Then $X$ has distribution $F(x)$*

---

Recognizing that $F$ is right continuous, I understand the importance of the supremum; yet, I'm having difficulty determining how to begin... It is clear I should show:

$$\displaystyle\lim_{z \to x-} F(x) = P[\sup\{z: F(z) < y\} < x]$$

Comment: I believe the solution follows from noting that the left limits of F(x) exist and stating the supremum in terms of this limit.